# Explanation of radix sort n x (k/d)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, radix

I have looked at the best, average and worst case time for the radix sort algorithm.

The average is N X K / D

I understand that N is the number of elements in the algorithm

I understand that K is the number of keys/buckets

Does anyone know what D represents?

I am going by the table on wikipedia, thanks

Reference - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Radix_sort

Comment: Depending on the sorting algorithm radix sort uses to sort, the best case might be exactly the same as worst case. This is the case if counting sort, for instance, is used. If bucket sort is used instead, then it depends on what sorting algorithm bucket sort uses. If it is insertion sort then best case != worst case.

Answer (score 4):

`D` is the number of digits in base `K`.

For example, if you have K = 16, and the largest number is `255`, `D = 2` `(16 ^ 2 = 256)`.  If you change `K` to 4, then `D`becomes 4 `(4 ^ 4 = 256)`.

Answer (score 1):

The running time of Radix Sort is commonly simplified to O(n), but there are several factors that can cause this running time to increase dramatically.

Assigning variables:

n = the number of elements to be sorted/n

L = the length of the elements aka the number of digits in each element

k = the range of the digits in each element (digits range from 1 to k)

The radix sort algorithm performs a bucket sort for each digit in every element. 
Therefore, L sorts must be done and each sort takes O(n+k) time because it is a bucket sort of n elements into k buckets. Therefore, the more accurate running time of Radix Sort is O(L(n+k)).

When the range of digits, k, is a small constant, as in decimal numbers, then the running time of Radix Sort can be simplified to O(Ln).

Due to these factors impacting the running time of the Radix Sort algorithm, there are certain considerations that need to be made about using the algorithm to perform a sort in order or it to be efficient. The data needs to:

1. have a fixed length (can choose to pad elements in order to create a uniform length for all elements)
2. have length of the elements, L, be linear in n
3. have the digit range, k, be linear in n